# Passing flashVars when testing in Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, flashvars

I can pass values from HTML to a SWF when running my own HTML file, but I cannot see the way to do this within Flex Builder.

Creating my own HTML file with an extra param in the object tag works fine:

```
<param name="flashVars" value="greeting=Hello"/>
```

Then I can use this ActionScript to get the value in Flex:

```
blah = Application.application.parameters.greeting
```

But clicking the "run" button in Flex Builder to test my application uses HTML that is built by the compiler and cannot be altered. Is there a way to set up parameters to pass into the Project? Thanks.

Comment: I should point out that the <param> elements are often ignored, and you ought to set the flashVars within the JavaScript call to AC_FL_RunContent (if that is being used in your situation) by adding a new line amongst the other parameters: 
    "flashVars", "greeting=Hello",

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Into your flex builder project you have normally a `html-template` directory containing an `index.template.html` file you can modify to suit your need.

Comment: Aha! I was editing the html file in the bin-debug folder (which gets overwritten on compile). Thanks Patrick!